# How to calculate the final position of a particle under variable accelaration and its instantenous velocity?

Tags: kinematics, velocity, differentiation

I'm a first-semester physics student who was recently on a train. On a screen, it said the instantaneous velocity of the train was 176 km / h. We had 4 min left until our destination. I wanted to calculate the distance based on these facts, so I tried using the kinematic equations. More specifically, this one: $X_f = X_i + \frac{1}{2} (V_{x_i} + V_{x_f}) t $, which worked, but I realized these kinematics equations are only valid for particles under constant acceleration. The train obviously speeds up and down depending on the road's curvature. My question is whether we can still model it using the average acceleration. We can think of it as beginning at $V_{x_i}$ (which is 176 km / h) and slowing down to 0 km / h over the course of 4 minutes. Does this model give us the same results? Why do we even need the term "particle under constant acceleration" then?

And the second part of my question. Would it be possible to calculate the instantaneous velocity of this train at any point t, only based on the given information? I wanted to take the derivative, but I don't have access to a function that gives us $x$ in terms of $t$. In all the questions I've solved so far, I was given a similar function. Something like $ x = t^3 $. Then it's easy to take its derivative, of course. Can we construct such a function on our own? How would we go about doing this?

This isn't my homework or anything. I was on a train and simply curious. Thank you!

Comment: Distance traveled is the area under the curve of the speed-time graph. So if you know that speeds and time stamps, you can use some geometry and approximations to find the area under the curve. Alternatively, you use calculus.

Comment: I see. Would my answer become more and more accurate with a greater quantity of time stamps? Say, I'm on the train. I check the instantaneous velocity on the screen every 30 seconds and jot it down. Then I take the trip again, but this time, I record the velocity every 15 seconds instead of 30. Is my area calculation more accurate with the 30-second stamps? I'm asking because I've always been given x as a function of time in problems. If x = t cubed, I can take the derivative of that and get a good result. But what happens when I don't have a function to go off of? Thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The time shown on the screen(4 mins) is also instantaneous and based on the speed of the train. That's why ETA decreases when you reach closer to the destination. So,
$d=V(inst) × t = 11.73 km$

No need of calculus here it seems.
About your second part, the relation of $x$ with $t$ generally appears when there is a constant external force in play. Like when the train reaches uphill and is rolling down with engine off on a defined curvature (gravitational force). Or a object thrown at an angle with some initial velocity, or a charged particle traveling in a constant or varying (defined by nature of its source) Magnetic field, etc.

Comment: Oh! That makes sense. Thank you!